# Android ViewModel MutableLiveData update multiple times

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata

**Scenario**

Hi,
I have an Activity with a ViewPager. In the ViewPagerAdapter, I create instances of a same fragment with different data.
And in each instance I initialize a ViewModel

```
val dataViewModelFactory = this.activity?.let { DataViewModelFactory(it) }
mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, dataViewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

In my fragment, I observe two MutableLiveData when I call APIs

```
mainViewModel.isResponseSuccessful.observe(this, Observer { it ->

        if(it) {
            //do Something
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error in Sending Request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


    })

    mainViewModel.isLoading.observe(this, Observer {
        if (it) {
            println("show progress")
        } else {
            println("dismiss progress")
        }
    })
```

In each fragment, on a button click I load another fragment. And if required call and API to fetch data.

**PROBLEM**

The code comes to the observe block multiple times in my fragment. When I comeback from one fragment to previous fragment, even though no API is called, the code on observe block is executed.

**What I tried**

I tried using an activity instance in the ViewModel initialization

```
mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity,dataViewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

But it did not work.

Please help,

Comment: When you "come back" to your fragment `ViewModelProvider` returns existing viewmodel instead of creating a new one so livedata might be already set and whatever value it holds is emitted.

Comment: @Pawel Yes, suppose in fragment A i made that value "true" and do all the processing I did. And then I go to  fragment B. Now when I come back to fragment A, it again emits the 'true' value? How can I prevent this, I do not want to do all the processing that I did while making it "true" the first time.

Comment: Either add a method that clears your livedatas when you "leave" your fragment or don't use viewmodel at all.

Comment: thanks, how can I clear my livedata @Pawel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent multiple calls of your observer u can just change `MutableLiveData` to `SingleLiveEvent`. Read [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)

Comment: In this case, if I am in my fragment A, call an API and show progressdialog, it will show only once and not for other API call. I want my livedata to be observed only when my fragment is on screen and do not hold the value for when I come back

Answer (score 1):

It might help you:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

class OneTimeEvent<T>(
    private val value: T
) {

    private val isConsumed = AtomicBoolean(false)

    private fun getValue(): T? =
        if (isConsumed.compareAndSet(false, true)) value
        else null

    fun consume(block: (T) -> Unit): T? =
        getValue()?.also(block)
}

fun <T> T.toOneTimeEvent() =
    OneTimeEvent(this)
```

First, when you want to post a value on `LiveData`, use `toOneTimeEvent()` extension function to wrap it in a `OneTimeEvent`:

```
liveData.postValue(yourObject.toOneTimeEvent())
```

Second, when you are observing on the `LiveData`, use `consume { }` function on the delivered value to gain the feature of `OneTimeEvent`. You'll be sure that the block of `consume { }` will be executed only once.

```
viewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer {
            it.consume { yourObject ->
                // TODO: do whatever with 'yourObject'
            }
        })
```

In this case, when the fragment resumes, your block of code does not execute again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent multiple calls of your observer just use *distinctUntilChanged* before observer.

```
mainViewModel.isResponseSuccessful.distinctUntilChanged().observe(this, Observer { it ->
        if(it) {
            //do Something
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error in Sending Request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })

mainViewModel.isLoading.distinctUntilChanged().observe(this, Observer {
        if (it) {
            println("show progress")
        } else {
            println("dismiss progress")
        }
})
```